# Why does React add "page" to the posts' route path?

Tags: reactjs

My site has URL built like this:

> www.mywebsite.com/page/:activePage .

This returns page no #activePage

> www.mywebsite.com/

This is the homepage which returns the first posts, and this is where the url is redirected if the requested url is www.mywebsite.com/page/1:

> www.mywebsite.com/:postLocation

This is the url of a post.
There are some other routes outside the scope of this issue. 
Right now the posts in the first page are rendered with the correct href but all the other pages get a 'page' between www.mywebsite.com and the postLocation. I am obviously doing something wrong in the router.

This is my router:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Page postsPerPage={3}/>} />
      <Route exact path="/Page/:activePage" render={(props) => 
          <Page key={props.match.params.activePage}  postsPerPage={3} {...props} />}/>
      <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/AddPost" component={AddPost}  />
      <Route path="/:postLocation" component={Post}  />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Manually requesting the faulty link loads (doesn't redirect however) the homepage. This might have something to do with the redirect logic I added in the Page component. If I remove the 'page' from the path then the page is loaded correctly.

The Page component is this:

```
const Page = ({postsPerPage}) =>
{
let {activePage} = useParams();
console.log('begin Page function; activePage = ' + activePage )

const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
const [redirectTo, setRedirctTo] = useState(false); 

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('begin UseEffect; activePage = ' + activePage )
    let intActivePage;

    if(activePage == '1') {
        setRedirctTo(true)
    }
    else {
        intActivePage = activePage == null ? 1: parseInt(activePage)
    }
    var take = postsPerPage;
    var skip = intActivePage ? (intActivePage-1) * postsPerPage : 0;
    var uri = `/api/posts?t=${take}&s=${skip}` 

    if (redirectTo == false)
    {
        fetch(uri)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(jsonResult => {console.log(jsonResult);setPosts(jsonResult)})
    }
    console.log('end UseEffect')

}, [])

if (redirectTo){
    return (<Redirect exact from="/Page/:activePage" to="/" />)
}


return (<div> 
    <ul>
        {posts.map(p => <li key={p.location}><PostPreview post={p}/></li>)}
    </ul>
</div>)
```

}

EDIT
So after a lot of staring at the code I realised it might have something to do with not having a '/' in the Links'to attribute.

Comment: what if you put the link manually in the browser are you able to render the page result ? if not can you please share with me what are the error seen in the console ?

Comment: Mannually requesting the link (without ''page' in the post's url) works fine. There is no error, and, I forgot to add - the faulty link loads (doesn't redirect however) the homepage. This might have something to do with the redirect logic I added in the Page component? I will update my initial post with the Page components as well.

Comment: i recommend first to never render a page instead render a component, therefore it will definitely fix your issue here. second your issue come from the props that you are currently sending that's not how stuff works in react

Comment: I am not sure I understand, what do you mean by rendering the component and not the page?